Keyboard and mouse settings for (clipboard) paste do not work anymore
Since two days my paste settings are gone.
In any application SHIFT-insert, mouse-right-paste, etc don't work anymore. Even in menu selection in any application edit->paste fails.
The only way to paste is the middle mouse button. All other options are "hijacked". I tried many things like dconf-editor. Tweaks middle button -> paste to "off", but nothing changes.
It almost impossible to anymore ...
Thanks.

Oh, I just found out that tweaks freezes.

you don't say which version of Ubuntu (but an educated guess is 24.04), You may wish to have regard to this article. Try uninstalling and re-installing the application.

Sorry, indeed Ubuntu  24.04.1 LTS
I Removed tweaks fully, as indicated in the link.
Restarted, but the problem still exists. The copied text is shown in gpaste, but I cannot past in Kate, Gedit, Firefox, etc.

It's getting worse, the paste option for file managers (Dolphin, Files) has disappeared.

I solved the problem. I changed, at login, to "ubuntu on wayland". Now "paste" is working again in all the applications.
Possible cause: after a of hibernation Ubuntu was frozen. I restarted, but I was not aware that another option was chosen at login. Though I was surprised that my external display was 'unset'. Since I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24, I thought that UI changes were caused by that.
Still strange, the number of options t login. See image.

